# Project Contains Error but not showing in source code Android

Tags: android, syntax-error

I import a pre-developed project in eclipse,in starting it shows me many errors.
After importing and including all the necessary files there are no error showing in my source code.

But whenever i tried to run the application it alert me that " There is error in my project".
But no errors are showing inside my project.

How can i fix my problem ?

This is what showing in my console in red color.

```
[2014-02-12 16:05:53 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/readystatesoftware/sqliteasset/SQLiteAssetException; [2014-02-12 16:05:53 - AClickCell_Orion] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/readystatesoftware/sqliteasset/SQLiteAssetException;
```

Comment: Because there are 2 android-support-v4 jar files available in your project.

Comment: have you tried clean and run again?

Comment: @InnocentKiller
noup...there is only one

Comment: Do you have any library project added in your project

Comment: @InnocentKiller
yes..FacebookSDK,actionbarsherlock

Comment: Then do one thing remove android support v4 library from your main project and add that same jar files from library project.

Comment: @InnocentKiller
android.support.v4 is showing in "Android Private Libraries" and i could not delete it

Comment: @JigarShekh, Do one thing first of all delete that jar file from your `lib` folder, go to your project's lib folder and delete directly from there and then open this project go to build path click on add external jar and add jar files from your library project. This will work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47310/discussion-between-innocentkiller-and-jigar-shekh)

Answer (score 1):

Go to lib folder and remove or delete android-support-v4 jar file. And clean and run. It will work.

Comment: This must be a comment. check above.

Comment: Then first make this as an comment if it worked for the users then you can ask user's to accept it...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project Properties > Java Build Path  and under Add Libraries Tab, remove Android Dependencies. Then right click on project, go to Android Tools and click Add supported Libraries. See if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Your project has two copies of the sqliteasset helper library. Remove one of them.